# Preferable django file structure

Tags: django

I have this 2 choices on which is the best to use or the best practice to implement in creating django project especially when it comes with the performance of the website.

I am currently using django 1.9

[image]

[image]

Comment: Best practice and other such opinionated questions are off-topic for SO; having said that, #2 is what most apps use; but this does not affect the performance of the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, project layout is unlikely to have any effect on performance.

If applicationForUser1 is quite separate in functionality from applicationForUser2, i'd split them into different apps. If you think the models/views belong together, combine them.

Without knowing what each app does i can't really give any more advise.  Lots of the time it really comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Performance has nothing to do with project structure, but I would suggest this project structure:

```
- project
  - conf (deployment confs)
  - mysite 
    - apps (all apps live here)
    - settings (all settings live here)
    - site-static (all static files live here)
    - templates
```

Comment: may I know why you recommend to have this kind of structure? (Note: I am also concerned with the maintenance of the project)